# Confused about the HTTP protocol

Tags: http, web-applications, client-server, protocols

I'm a little confused about the HTTP protocol, from what i know HTTP was made for delivering web pages and primarily sending messages between a web server and a browser. 
But it seems that HTTP is used anywhere in a lot of apps that indeed uses the internet for communicating but are not web application("application that uses a web browser as a client").

I'm asking this because i started developing an iPhone app (kind of navigation app) and i need to send messages between the iPhone client and my server. Now people keep telling me to use HTTP protocol, but is this really the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is valid, if I can restate, why are we using HTTP for every Server-Client communications while it was meant typically for browser-web server use case and can be less efficient compared to direct TCP communication. My reasons below :

- HTTP protocol is extremely simple and like many things in tech simplicity trumps complexity even if the complex solution is more efficient (unless by a huge margin).
- HTTP protocol is stateless making it much simpler to scale horizontally by adding more machines and balance load by simple load balancing techniques like round robin.
- Easy to find a reasonable and free HTTP server to get your app up and running soon than implementing your own protocols, servers and taking your focus away from the real problem you want to solve.
- Like any simple technology used by many parties, it gets better with time and with modern features like Keep-Alive, chunked transfer, pipelining you can overcome some drawbacks of connections overheads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get the benefit of using HTTP but what if I need to send messages from server to client? how do I do it with stateless protocol? The server does not keep open sockets so how could it send a message to a client?

Comment: It depends, stateless protocol has its advantages as longs as your can design your requirement around it and reap the benefits of your server being stateless. But that doesn't mean all applications can be pushed into that usecase. A typical way to maintain state in http is at client side using cookies. Now there are many workarounds to satisfy your usecase like 'Hanging GET/COMET' or the newer WebSockets.

Comment: Another reason that it's widely used on the Internet and it's friendly to the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's the way to go. How else do you want to go about it?

```
Web Server <-------HTTP-------> Client
```

Client can be a browser, a mobile phone, an xbox. Anything on the receiving end of a server request is a client.

Comment: Yes, HTTP is the way to go for networked client/server communication. We are now (finally) seeing a massive shift away from SOAP madness to HTTP. @Eyal: make sure you check out REST (and the REST vs SOAP wars of 2001-2010) if you are interested in the fascinating issues behind decentralized networked systems.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that the move to REST and QUERY from SOAP is a good thing.
We are currently implementing a system that will use HTTP as the bidirectional transfer mechanism.
The response back to uploads to the server is a standard HTTP response such as 200 = success with no body.
The response to a query is an ASCII text page with the answer as the body. We then just turn the ASCII back to binary to use the data.
The advantage of this method is that you just have to provide the right URL and parameters and you can handle everything.
Unless your protocol stack knows how to format post and get requests, then you will need to do that yourself. While this is tedious it is well documented at [W3C Protocols](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/%22W3C%20Protocols%22) however it is a bit tedious to have to go through it all yourself. So if you are having to fo that then I recommend getting an eBook to help sort out the details. Some examples are:
[HTTP](http://search.oreilly.com/?q=HTTP&x=0&y=0)

Answer (score 0):

https stands for Hyper Text Transfer Text, it helps communicate a client with the server. The client is called a device being made request, server is called handling that request, there four methods. For example when you get into some website your browser will make request in order to get html, css, js and other file, and also images if they need (GET method). Another example you can see in a lot of website form which you need to fill to get into system it is called (POST method). Also if you have a post for example in facebook, and you want to rewrite or edit this post it is called (PUT method), you will change only one content without touching another one. And the last one is (DELETE method), it is used when you want delete something in facebook